# Will instance properties obscure the prototype chain?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

**Snippet A**

```
var instance = [];

Array.prototype.forEach = function () {var prototyped_version;}

instance.forEach = function () {var property_version};
```

In snippet A, if I add properties to the instance variable `instance`, and accidentally write over a prototyped method (in this case `forEach`), which method will actually be called when I execute:

```
instance.forEach()
```

the prototyped version or the property version?

I'm trying to figure out why [underscore](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L78) seems to have complex type checking, particularly, this line:

```
if (nativeForEach && obj.forEach === nativeForEach) {
```

Why not just:

```
if (obj.forEach) {
```

as `obj` has already been verified to not be `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: *"which method will actually be called"* => this can be easily tested. Did you do it ?

Comment: The property version will always be used. In the prototypical inheritance model you check if the object has the property defined and go up the property chain if it does not.

Comment: The underscore check `obj.forEach===nativeForEach` checks to make sure not only that `forEach` has not been redefined on this particular array, but also that the object's `forEach` is identical to the native Array method, which might not be the case if the object is not an Array (and thus does not inherit from `Array.prototype`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I found is that this will over-write the prototyped version.  Even if you assign the prototype version after the property assignment.

Here it the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RmCGL/).  Logging the function will print it out and you can inspect it in the console and see that it is the property version.

**Fiddle Code:**

```
var instance = [];

instance.forEach = function () {var property_version};

Array.prototype.forEach = function () {var prototyped_version;}

console.log(instance.forEach);
```

Instance properties will over-write prototyped methods.

Comment: It doesn't overwrite it just has higher priority. JavaScript will check for the function on the object instance first before considering the prototype.

Comment: There is hardly anything more basic about how prototypes work in JavaScript.